# How to add a lightning application in to the Salesforce1 application?

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-apps, lightning-connect

I have added lightning component to salesforce1 application. But is there any way to add a lightning application to S1 app? Because lightning component can't add script files. Therefore I can't load scripts files to the lightning component.Is there any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add script and css file in your component controller using java script

1) add following line into your yourcomp.cmp file

```
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
```

2) Add doInit function into yourcompController.js

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
       helper.assets();
    }
})
```

3) Add following code into yourcompHelper.js

```
({
  assets : function() {
        this.loadCSS('/resource/assets/css/mycss.css', function() {
            console.log('Loaded mycss.css');
        });
        this.loadJS('/resource/assets/js/jquery.js', function() {
            console.log('Loaded jquery.js ');
        });
  },
    loadJS : function(source, callback) {
        console.log('Going to load '+source+ ' java script file')
        var loadScript = document.createElement('script');
        loadScript.setAttribute('src', source);
        loadScript.onload = callback;
        document.body.appendChild(loadScript);
    },
    loadCSS : function(source, callback) {
        console.log('Going to load '+source+ ' style file')
        var fileref = document.createElement('link');
        fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
        fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
        fileref.setAttribute("href", source);
        fileref.onload = callback;
        document.head.appendChild(fileref);
    }
})
```

> Note: Your static path should be correct.